# How to put 2 different migrations in the same div ?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

by advance, sorry for my English, 
I have a problem with my plans/view. I want to add to different migrations called "plan" & "addplan" in the same div. 
Something like that :

```
<% @plans.each do |plan| && @addplans.each do |addplan| %>
 <div class="plan_container">
<%= plan.price %>
<%= addplan.property %>
<p>pr</p>
<%= link_to "#{plan.name} (#{plan.amount})",
    new_subscription_path(plan_id: plan.id) %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

of course, this code can't work but I can't find a solution to solve my problem. 
Maybe it could be easier. 
I'm using stripe with service objects to create my plans, like that :

```
class CreatePlan
def self.call(options={})
    plan = Plan.new(options)

    if !plan.valid?
    return plan
end

begin
    Stripe::Plan.create(
                    id: options[:stripe_id],
                    amount: options[:amount],
                    currency: 'eur',
                    interval: options[:interval],
                    name: options[:name],
                    price: options[:price],
                    )
                    rescue Stripe::StripeError => e
                    plan.errors[:base] << e.message
                    return plan
    end

    plan.save

    return plan
end
end
```

Unfortunately, when I attempt to add a new column in my plans, the new one is not recognize by Stripe. So, the only way I found is to create a new model with new columns.
I hope this is clear, and somebody could help me :).

Answer (score 0):

What you are referring to as "migrations" should more properly be called "collections", which is a word for an array where all the elements are the same kind, in this case model instances.  A migration is a little script which changes your database schema.

It's not clear (to me at least) what you actually want to do.  If you want to  add two arrays together and iterate over the results you could just do

```
(arr1 + arr2).each do |obj|
  #obj could be an object from arr1 or arr2
```

However, this feels like a clumsy workaround for the actual problem, which you haven't really explained.

If i was you, i would delete this question, which is just confusing, and instead make a new question which addresses the problem of

"Unfortunately, when I attempt to add a new column in my plans, the new one is not recognize by Stripe."

I'm sure this problem is solvable, if you were to explain it properly.  Don't just give up and try some other nonsensical solution, then ask why your nonsensical solution doesn't work, that's just a waste of time.

Comment: Thank you, I will do it now